# Flatness over non-reduced schemes : no geometric characterisation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness, reference-request

I know someone already asked about  [flatness over non-reduced schemes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16465/flatness-over-non-reduced-schemes), but I think my question is different.

I'm reading Bosch, Lütkebohmert and Raynaud's "Néron models", and in the second chapter, they swiftly discuss some background material of algebraic geometry, notably flatness in section 2.4.

They mention first on page 52 that when the base has nilpotents : "there exists no criterion to test flatness by geometric properties".

On page 53, again they tease : "It is impossible to characterize the flatness of an S-scheme X of finite type by geometric properties when the base S is not reduced." Then they go on pointing EGA IV(2) 6.9.1 for the reduced case.

What had they in mind exactly?

Comment: To complement Sándor's answer, the "identity map" $X_{red}\to X$
is generally not flat. In fact generic flatness (EGA IV 6.9.1) will
fail for the simplest example $Spec k\to Spec k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$.

Comment: @Donu Arapura: counter-examples will tell "This isn't a geometric characterisation of flatness" ; they won't give "There is no geometric characterisation of flatness"... (And I did mention they were referencing EGA IV(2) 6.9.1)

Comment: I'm aware of both of those facts. It's possible
you're asking the wrong people.

Comment: @Donu Arapura: you sound like you feel offended ; that was definitely not the goal : I'm sorry if my comment went through as this.

I'm asking the question precisely because I have the impression there was something deep I was missing.

In fact, I'm not exactly sure what they mean by "geometric property"... it must not be about topology (or they would have used that word), it must not be purely algebraic (geometry is often opposed to algebra... as two sides of the same coin).

Comment: The internet seems to be an imperfect medium for communication.
Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Snark: Your comment does read a little aggressive. I am sure you did not mean it that way, but it's good to try to think about it how it might sound to someone else. Then again, I have made the same mistake a number of times and probably will again...

Comment: p.s.: It also makes a difference when you make comments under your real name (like Donu and I). There is a tendency to be more careless when one is posting under a pseudonym. Cheers!


Comment: What annoys me most is that when I started my comment with "@..." I knew I needed to be careful -- and that wasn't enough. My real name is in my profile.... what I thought would be a login name ended up being the displayed name. Perhaps I should change that...

Comment: Just as you, I did not mean to offend you (and I tried to make that clear). Your real name is not displayed to anyone else, but it is an understandable mistake.

Comment: I can't help but wonder why there is both "Display name" and "Real name"... and one is hidden anyway, but now I changed both to the same.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what **they** had in mind, but one possible interpretation of this is that you cannot "see" the difference between a non-reduced scheme and its induced reduced scheme structure geometrically, because they have the same set of points.

A non-reduced scheme is the same *topological* space as a reduced scheme with extra functions, so you have to take these extra functions into account and that is inherently algebraic.

In other words, you cannot expect to have a condition that says something about the dimension of the fibers or components (associated points) dominating the base like in criteria over reduced bases.

---

**OK**, let me try to give a more complex answer. Take the simple flatness criterion that

> > **Theorem**
> >
> > Let $f:X\to B$ be a morphism such that $B$ is integral, regular, and of dimension $1$. Then $f$ is flat if and only if every associated point of $X$ dominates $B$.

This is not a topological characterization, because it allows $X$ to have embedded points, yet it requires $B$ to be reduced. I suppose you could argue that the part of the condition of the theorem that applies to $B$ is indeed topological, but I would not expect anybody call this criterion topological.

Most other flatness criteria require something about the fibers of the map, which is again only topological on the base, but more than that on the total space and/or fibers.

Also, one might argue that when someone says topological with respect to an algebraic scheme they might mean the euclidean or the étale topology. In some sense to work with the Zariski topology is already a little bit geometric rather than topological.

I realize that this may not sound satisfactory to you, but I think many remarks authors make do not hide some big secret. If they had some complex picture in mind when they wrote it, I bet they would have said more. Then again, I do not claim to know what was/is on their mind. As Donu suggests you could ask the authors. If you do, please share the answer with us!!

Comment: Indeed, a scheme isn't just a topological space ; but they chose to write "geometric" not "topologic"... that is why I'm expecting a more complex answer somehow :-/

Comment: I guess Y=B? I'm also surprised that this remark came twice, but they didn't give references : they're so generous about pointers everywhere else...

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wanted to use $B$ instead of $Y$ to show that it is different than in your question. Clearly I immediately forgot. It is corrected now.
